# Java exception handling

Tags: java, exception

so I'm kind of new to catching errors and such. Anyways, the program is supposed to ask the user for 2 integers and then add them together. Simple, but if either of the numbers are not integers, than an error is thrown. Currently, if I enter 2 integers, instead of adding them, it just restarts the getAnswer() method and outputs them again. Also, if you enter more than one error, it will simply exit.

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaApplication1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Intro();
    System.out.println("Your answer: "+getAnswer());
  }
  private static void Intro() {
    System.out.println("Hello this program adds 2 integers together and catches errors.");
    getAnswer();
  }
  private static int getAnswer() throws InputMismatchException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
      System.out.println("Please input a number");
      int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Please input a second number");
      int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
      return num1+ num2;
    } catch (InputMismatchException exp) {
      System.out.println("Exception thrown");
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a debug point in the `getAnswer()` method and stepping through it? Also, if you catch a particular kind of exception, the method signature no longer needs to say `throws <whatever>Exception`.

Comment: "Currently, if I enter 2 integers, instead of adding them, it just restarts the getAnswer() method and outputs them again" - yeah, because your program contains two calls to `getAnswer`, and you throw the first result away.

Comment: Do you not want it to exit on error?

Comment: There is no question in this question...

Comment: The name `Intro` violates the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling  `getAnswer();` totally two times, so you just remove the call from  `Intro()` method which will solve the problem.

```
private static void Intro() {
        System.out.println("Hello this program adds 2 
             integers together and catches errors.");
}
```

If you want to prompt the user to reenter the input again, you can call the `getAnswer()` in the `catch` block as shown below:

```
private static int getAnswer() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
        System.out.println("Please input a number");
        int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please input a second number");
        int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
       return num1+ num2;
         } catch (InputMismatchException exp) {
           System.out.println("Exception thrown, please reenter values:");
           getAnswer();
        }
       return 0;
 }
```

---

One more point is that rather than catching the `InputMismatchException`, the other better way is read the inputs as strings and validate that they contain only numeric values like below:

```
private static int getAnswer() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a number");
        String num1 = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please input a second number");
        String num2 = scanner.nextLine();
        if(num1.matches("[0-9]+") && num2.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            return Integer.parseInt(num1)+ Integer.parseInt(num2);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Your inputs contain Invalid characters");
            getAnswer();
        }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: And under the `catch` block he should change the return to `return getAnswer();` if he wants it to keep running and ask again.

Comment: Ah, fixed that issue, but now it exits when the program catches the exception.

Comment: really shouldn't use catching the exception as the control behavior for asking for correct input. Should read in both values and verify they are integers, then continue else output incorrect input and retry.

Comment: I appreciate it, it's been a long day, I thought exceptions were basically supposed to restart the method they were thrown from?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I agree with you

Comment: @Cory The best way is rather than catching the exception, read the input fields as string and then you validate `if(num1.matches("[0-9]+") && num2.matches("[0-9]+"))`

Comment: plus 1 for the correct handling of the inputs in the last example

Comment: @Cory, "I thought exceptions were basically supposed to restart the method they were thrown from?" No, they're supposed to abruptly exit from the operation that encounters them.